# how to detect two finger touch in emulator in android

Tags: android, gesture

I need to detect the double touch in emulator, while running my app. I used ScaleGestureDetector in my app. I need to check that in my emulator. In iPhone by pressing option, we can use the two finger touch.  Is there any way to use the ScaleGestureDetector in emulator.

Answer (score 2):

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/03/updated-sdk-tools-and-adt-revision-17.html

"After adding webcam support and sensor emulation, we are adding experimental support for Multi-Touch input through a tethered Android device." ....

But it looks like "This requires an Android 4.0 or later system image."

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use two-finger pan you need to right click. On a Mac with a trackpad you would need to plug in a mouse or switch your secondary click to bottom corner. Then you can hold the command button. Otherwise hold the command button to see the finger indicators then click and drag to pinch/zoom